# How to insert data into a specific cell in csv with python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am trying to insert data into a specific cell in csv. My code is as follows.

The existing file.

[image]

Output

The data in cell A1("Custmor") is replaced with new data("Name").

[image]

My code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

#The existing CSV file
file_source = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Customer.csv"

#Read the existing CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(file_source)

#Insert"Name"into cell A1 to replace "Customer"
df[1][0]="Name"

#Save the file
df.to_csv(file_source, index=False)
```

And it doesn't work. Please help me finding the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Customer` is column header, you need do

```py
df = df.rename(columns={'Customer': 'Name'})
```

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are going to want to work with header less csv so if that's the case, your code is already correct, just need to add `header=None` while reading from csv

```
import pandas as pd

#The existing CSV file
file_source = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Customer.csv"

#Read the existing CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(file_source,header=None) #notice this line is now different

#Insert"Name"into cell A1 to replace "Customer"
df[1][0]="Name"

#Save the file
df.to_csv(file_source, index=False,header=None) #made this header less too
```

Comment: The cell the OP tries to modify **is** a header. Trying to consider headers as part of the data is a very bad choice.